# Build failed with an exception : could not get unknown property 'mergeResourcesProvider'

Tags: react-native, build.gradle

After i install @expo/vector-icons
i can't build my application again with this error appear.

*Where

Script 'C:\Users\Mostafa\SecurityEye\node_modules\react-native\react.gradle' line: 95

A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> could not get unknown property 'mergeResourcesProvider' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApplicationVariantImpl.

line 95:

> variant.mergeResourcesProvider.get().dependsOn(currentBundleTask)

Comment: @Usama isn't vector icons already included in expo?

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/icons/

Comment: it should be, but after i installed expo i couldn't find it. so i installed it separately.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can update gradle version  to 4.10.1 android buildtool to 3.3.0